# Getting type of "this" in C++ when defining non-static member

Tags: c++, templates, types

I'm trying to do some fancy template stuff and I've stumbled on a problem: I would like to get the type of a class, inside its definition, while defining a non-static member. Is this possible? (In any C++ version.)

---

Take the following code:

```
template<typename T>
struct inner {
    T* this_;
    /* fancy stuff... */
};

struct foo {
    inner<foo> bar{this};
};
```

The class `foo` has a non-static member `bar` that is initialized with the pointer `foo* this`. This code compiles in clang and gcc.

But I actually want the definition of `inner` to appear in a macro, which means I don't have the string `foo` to use in the line `inner<foo> bar{this}`. Trying to use:

`inner bar{this};`

in C++17, which allows template argument deduction for class templates, produces the error

> error: use of class template 'inner' requires template arguments; argument deduction not allowed in non-static struct member `inner bar{this};`

which I understand. Trying:

`inner<decltype(*this)> bar{this};`

produces a similar looking error:

> error: invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function `inner<decltype(*this)> bar{this};`

---

As a workaround, I've been using the following curiously recurring template pattern:

```
template<typename T>
struct SelfAwareType {
    using myOwnType = T;
}

struct foo : SelfAwareType<foo> {
    inner<myOwnType> bar{this};
};
```

Comment: After the beginning of a class' definition until it's end, the class is a declared but incomplete type. During the context of it's definition, it cannot be used where a complete type is required.

Comment: Confused by: _"...to appear in a macro..."_: macro substitution/expansion happens well before template type deduction. So how can you get a deduced type into a previous phase of compilation?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Yeah, that's what I thought. But then why does the `inner<foo>` work?

Comment: @DrorSpeiser A template argument does not necessarily need to be a complete type.

Comment: @RichardCritten: I'm not trying to get a deduced type during preprocessing, I'm trying to get the type without using its real name during compilation, like decltype works :)

Comment: is there any reason you can't use `auto`?

Comment: @DrorSpeiser In your first example, `T` is never required to be a complete type, so you can provide `foo` to it while it's still incomplete. Notice that in that case, the `this_` member is a pointer to `T`. If you had something like `T my_t;` or something similar, then it would complain because then `T` would need to be a complete type.

Comment: There is a [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0874r0.html) proposing a language feature for this purpose, but it hasn’t been reviewed at all yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you can constrain all foo's to require a typedef 'this_type' then your macro could be free of needing to specify foo.

```
template<typename T>
struct inner {
    T* this_;
    /* fancy stuff... */
};

struct foo {
    typedef foo this_type ;
    inner<this_type> bar{this};
};
```

which is basically the same as your 'workaround' without having to use crtp and introduce another type.